# How can I refactor my code to separate concerns of formula computation from logging intermediate formula values?

Tags: php, logging, refactoring, single-responsibility-principle

I am looking for a specific refactoring advice.

First, I had a script with computations only and no output.  I wanted to code up output of computations so both formulas and their actual formula values were seen on the screen.

And so I have implemented a `DEBUG` variable and have added output statements to show when `DEBUG` value is `true`.  My problem though is that my output code ended up being tightly coupled with computation.

My code now looks like so:

```
$rows = db_query("select..*");
foreach($rows as row)
{
    $description = $row['model'];

    //dump() prints output on screen
    if ($this->DEBUG) dump("<h1>Trying {$description}...</h1>");

    if ($this->DEBUG) dump("Checking Speed . . . ");
    $this->calcSpeed();

    if ($this->DEBUG) dump("Checking Flow . . . ");
    $this->checkFlow();
}
```

And then inside `calcSpeed` for example I have computation and output:

```
$this->ratio = $this->r / $this->q;
$this->n = ($factor * $this->vel);
$this->t = $this->n * pow($this->r, 0.5) / pow(($this->reject * 2), 0.75);
$this->p = $this->n * pow($this->q, 0.5) / pow(($this->feed * 2), 0.75);

if ($this->DEBUG) dump("<b>Computing Speed</b>");
if ($this->DEBUG) dump("ratio ({$this->ratio})= r({$this->r}) / q({$this->q})");
if ($this->DEBUG) dump("N ({$this->n})= (factor ({$factor}) * vel ({$this->vel})");
if ($this->DEBUG) dump("T ({$this->t}) = N({$this->n}) * QR({$this->q})^0.5 / (reject ({$this->reject}) * 2) ^ 0.75");
if ($this->DEBUG) dump("P ({$this->p}) = N ({$this->n}) * Q({$this->q})^0.5 / (feed ({$this->feed}) * 2)^ 0.75");
```

What I have above is tightly coupled and ideally I'd like to remove that coupling and have `computation` be separate from `computation output`.  I do not see how to do this cleanly and without duplicating computation.  I want to see output of all the intermediate values and not just the end result.

Comment: Just trying to understand a bit more, you still want to output the data if debug is true but you don't want the code to be inside where the computations are going on?

Comment: yes.  And I think separating these concerns will be "better"(tm).  And just to note that if it's not really better and if what I have is just fine, then it will work for me as well.  I just feel that having them both in the same place is messy.

Comment: At least extract this to a function for example `if ($this->DEBUG) { $this->log(); }`

Comment: yes, but it's just moving the "problem" elsewhere - it's still in the same file, and is just an indirection-call away, still connected in the same place.  But it will likely look cleaner...

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a super-nice (that I know of - if there is please tell me!) way to log that is not encapsulated with the code you are logging however...

You could hide away the logging for each variable by using the get/set methodology.

**Get/Set method with magic methods:**

You would need to amend the class holding the variables to act like the following:

Change variable to be private

Variable must match the name of the get/set methods (e.g. ratio => getratio/setratio)

Implement the get/set/__get and __set methods

Added a logger method to do the if statement for you to keep the get/set methods as clean as possible

```
class MyClass
{
    private $ratio;

    // Setter method
    // Allows for additional work when setting the value
    // Here we can output the log as we want then set the value
    public function setratio($ratio)
    {
         logger("ratio ({$this->ratio})= r({$this->r}) / q({$this->q})");
         $this->ratio = $ratio;
    }

    // Getter method
    // Allows for additional work when getting the value
    // Here we can just retrieve the value of the variable
    public function getratio()
    {
        return $this->ratio;
    } 

    // Magic Method __set
    // Here we are able to use Variable Function calls to call the appropriate setter
    // This is automatically called when using the syntax $this->ratio = value where ratio is a private property
    public function __set($name, $value) 
    {
        $functionName ='set'.$name;
        return $this->$functionName($value);
    }

    // Magic Method __get
    // Here we are able to use Variable Function calls to call the appropriate getter
    // This is automatically called when using the syntax $this->ratio where ratio is a private property
    public function __get($name) 
    {
        $functionName = 'get'.$name;
        return $this->$functionName();
    }

    // Custom function for logging. Only need to call this and it'll check DEBUG for us
    public function logger($message)
    {
        if ($this->DEBUG) 
            dump($message);
    }
}
```

This way when you call `calcSpeed` you just have

```
$this->ratio = $this->r / $this->q;
$this->n = ($factor * $this->vel);
$this->t = $this->n * pow($this->r, 0.5) / pow(($this->reject * 2), 0.75);
$this->p = $this->n * pow($this->q, 0.5) / pow(($this->feed * 2), 0.75);
```

Although this will only work for the variables being set and not just random calls to dump so unfortunately they will have to stay where they are, however you could move them into the methods themselves to tidy up the loop a bit and also use the logger method to remove the ifs.

This would tidy the loop to by the following:

```
$rows = db_query("select..*");
foreach($rows as row)
{
    $description = $row['model'];

    //dump() prints output on screen
    $this->logger("<h1>Trying {$description}...</h1>");
    $this->calcSpeed();
    $this->checkFlow();
}
```

and each method to be

```
function calcSpeed()
{
    $this->logger("Checking Speed . . . ")
    $this->ratio = $this->r / $this->q;
    $this->n = ($factor * $this->vel);
    $this->t = $this->n * pow($this->r, 0.5) / pow(($this->reject * 2), 0.75);
    $this->p = $this->n * pow($this->q, 0.5) / pow(($this->feed * 2), 0.75);
    // Any other code
}

function checkFlow()
{
    $this->logger("Checking Flow . . . ")
    // Rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a general thought-guideline, which can take quite a bit of work to implement, but may be worth it:

**treat formulas as data** (and treat data for the formulas also as data).

For PHP there is a library called `symfony/expression-language`, which allows you to evaluate and interpret formulas.  With it it is possible to compile and interpret custom formulas.

Thus I believe it is possible to do something like this:

- encode formulas into a database to be used as one true source of formulas
- (optional) use the library to compile statements into PHP code
- interpret formulas from database via the library, for computation and for logging purposes

**Sample Code**

```php
$expressions = //load from database
$language = new \Symfony\Component\ExpressionLanguage();
$data = array(); //storage of intermediate results.
foreach ($expressions as $expression)
{
    /*
     * Evaluate the formula
     */
    $data[$expression->getVariable()] = 
        $language->evaluate($expression->getExpression(), $data);

    /*
     * Add facilities to output the formulas/expressions here:
     * example only, where a and b defined in previously-processed formulas
     */
     print $expression->getVariable() . ' = ' .       //c =
           $expression->getExpression() . ' = ' .     //sqrt(a**2+b**2) =
           data[$expression->getVariable()] . '<br>'; //5<br>
}
```